# Drag and Drop word document onto Silverlight 4 web part within a SharePoint 2010 web page

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2010

User should be able to drag and drop a word document onto a SharePoint 2010 web page and the content in the word document must be displayed on the page (including images, format etc.)

Any ideas on how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: more than 100 views and no one replied yet?

Comment: 100 views on an item with a bounty is not surprising.... No answers to a very specialised question is also not surprising. SharePoint developers get paid a premium for good reason and are probably busy working elsewhere. Sorry.

Comment: @Hitech: I started the bounty after 100 views with no reply :(

Comment: See you finally got an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to bake your own solution here. Luckily, you should be able to get started with [TextGlow](http://textglow.codeplex.com/), which renders docx files in Silverlight. It has an intermediate level of formatting accounted for, but more can be programmed in. It's also SL2.0, so it will need to be updated and customized to meet your needs. See a demo at: http://www.textglow.com/

Then, wrap it in a SharePoint webpart and account for Drag/Drop, etc. There are a lot of good intro videos on [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/search?term=silverlight%20sharepoint) about this and lots of other blogs elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I evaluated textGlow, telerik's radRichTextBox and some others. Nothing seems to work fine as it supposed to (especially the formatting)  I have decided NOT to implement the solution based on the cost, time and ROI factor. For now users have to adjust with SharePoint Workspace and other OOB alternatives :(